# How to set localStorage value to false?

Tags: javascript, boolean, local-storage

I want to add `false` to `localStorage['flag'] = false` I tried:

```
localStorage['flag'] = false;
localStorage['flag'] = 0;
```

but when I check

```
if(!localStorage['flag']){
  //this will never happen
}
/**or**/
if(localStorage['flag']){
  //this will happen always
}
```

fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/qqew0zzf/

Comment: As far as I know, local storage save only string.. try to print the stored value and you will see

Answer (score 7):

You can use `setItem` and `getItem` to store your flag.  Keep in mind this will give you "false" back after using `getItem`, which is the reason your original attempt failed (the string 'false' is not a falsey value).  Quite often JSON is used to save and retreive objects in local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem('flag', false);
var flag = localStorage.getItem('flag');
//flag is "false"
```

Using JSON:

```
localStorage.setItem('flag', JSON.stringify(false));
var flag = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('flag'));
//flag is the boolean false
```

Comment: I wonder why the browser doesn't do that by default. I can't see any justification for the current behavior.